# JSF facets not available in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, facet

So I am watching a tutorial about how to configure JSF in eclipse. I understand that you click file -> new -> Dynamic Web Project.

And then it gives you a few options. The Target Runtime will be (for me) Apache Tomcat version 8, and dynamic web module version will be 3.0. And in the configuration drop-down you are supposed to see Java Server Faces 2.0v or 2.1v, but I do not have that option.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen if you started with plain "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" instead of with "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" and then manually added some plugins on it. Throw away your current Eclipse install and restart clean with "[Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](https://eclipse.org/downloads/)".

Answer (score -1):

If you dont see the JSF options, then its not part of your original eclipse version. In that case, you need to download the extra tools that you want. Go to Help -> Install New Software and then type the following URL in the box `http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler` This URL is for Kepler version of Eclipse. You need to change it according to your eclipse version. jBossTools have JSF features. Restart the eclipse once the s/w is installed successfully.

Comment: That's JBoss Tools, not Eclipse.

Comment: @BalusC, Yes, I know that its JBoss Tools. Thats what I mentioned in my post as well. Asked him to add the extra plugins, in case he is using the very old eclipse where JSF is not part of it. I assumed that. This will also fix the issue. Do you see my answer does not fix?

Comment: JSF Facets are not part of JBoss Tools. They have always been part of Eclipse for Java EE. OP just used the wrong (not old) version of Eclipse.